# How do I write the value of a variable to a dos text file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

How do I write a variable value to a text file within a dos batch script?

(Y, JJJ, SERL, and SERIAL are variables in the batch file)

I tried the following:

```
set SERIAL=%Y%+%JJJ%+%SERL% 
%SERIAL% > VAR_1.TXT
%T% > VAR_2.TXT
%A% > VAR_3.TXT
%SERL% > VAR_4.TXT
```

The files VAR_!.txt, VAR_2.txt, VAR_3.txt, VAR_4.txt are created, but they are empty (0 bytes).

I know this has a simple solution, but it has been 20+ years since I played with batch files (VERY rusty!)

THANKS!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This method allows long filenames and also stops the trailing spaces from being included in the files (the spaces are to stop other problems, but this method is preferable).

The `(` characters are a good practice to avoid another bug in `echo`.

```
>"VAR_1.TXT" echo(%SERIAL%
>"VAR_2.TXT" echo(%T%
>"VAR_3.TXT" echo(%A%
>"VAR_4.TXT" echo(%SERL%
```

Comment: I used this solution...WORKS GREAT, and no trailing spaces!  Kudos to you.

Answer (score 6):

Try using `echo` to get the value out?

```
echo %SERIAL% > VAR_1.TXT
echo %T% > VAR_2.TXT
echo %A% > VAR_3.TXT
echo %SERL% > VAR_4.TXT
```

Comment: Not to belittle you but there are reasons why the format you are using is to be avoided.  See my answer for a more reliable method.

Comment: @foxidrive, I didn't know about your method, and I appreciate the tip. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please note, that variables can be hidden from global context if used inside  SETLOCAL ENDLOCAL block.

Also If You want to append instead to create new file You can use >>

```
SETLOCAL 
CALL SET B="fiiLOCAL"
echo %A% > VAR_1.TXT
SET A="fooGLOB2"
echo %B% >> VAR_1.TXT
ENDLOCAL
TYPE var_1.txt
```